# The column that could "keep its center point". What can I do?

Tags: flutter, dart, layout, widget

I would like to ask for help with inserting widgets into a Center(). Center is a child of Row.
I mean, I've got two Containers (50, 100) and (50,50) and I need to place them in a column/stack that's a child of the Center, but I must place them that way:
Sometimes the containers will be created dynamically basing on the other objects and I can't predict the exact ratio or their size and I can't use Expanded because Row is a child of List.
I just want to keep the center at the exact same point and force the column to insert children without changing the position of the center.

and I can't predict the size of the numerator and denominator. But it must keep the "fraction bar" exactly at the center without changing its position, no matter how tall the numerator or denominator might be.

I MEAN:

I got ----------- <----- this "point" that's center
and I want to place two items at the top and at the bottom WITHOUT changing the position of the center.
Example
Center is (0,0)

I place numerator and denominator.
It should be placed like

nominator -> since the fraction bar to the top.

and denominator since the fraction bar to the bottom.
Currently, when I'm using the column and numerator has height: 200, and denominator: 100.
Remember both numerator and denominator are created dynamically, I can't use expanded or anything else, because I don't know it's size.
The center becomes: (0, 50). But I want to keep it (0,0).

Comment: You could add the code you have so far to the question instead of describing it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have understood your question, You are trying to divide the list by two containers which should maintain a constant size. Here you can define the width and height of each containers. But the only problem here is it works fine on mobiles but it is opened on tablets then the container width and height of the containers needs to be redefined for tablet view. Else it looks untidy.